# Two Databases Two Domains with Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on a laravel script that was compiled for me. Going through I decided to create two domains that would access the same script but call different databases. I don't know much about laravel and I don't believe I can recompile code but here is the current database call:

```
<?php 
return array('db_host' => 'mysql.com', 'db_name' => 'database',      'db_user' =>    'myusername', 'db_password' => 'password123');
```

I'm trying to do something like this code:

```
<?php $url = Request::url();

if (strpos($url, "greymafia")!==false){
 return array('db_host' => 'mysql.com', 'db_name' => 'database',      'db_user' =>    'myusername', 'db_password' => 'password123');
}
if (strpos($url, "pinvy")!==false){
return array('db_host' => 'mysql.com', 'db_name' => 'database',      'db_user' =>    'myusername', 'db_password' => 'password123');

}
```

Comment: use [**environment configuration**](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration)

Comment: You are misusing the word "compile".

Comment: The script is hosted on the same machine. How could I tell it to check the domain name its under?

Comment: these are sub domain or domain?

Comment: Both are domains that have pointers to the same folder location